# Não Preencher nova coluna como Null e sim com valor especifico no script

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, script, sql-server-express

Tenho uma tabela especifica no banco de dados, nela eu guardo informações de turmas que são criadas, turmas de natação, turmas de futsal, turmas de musculação e por ai vai, ela já esta em uso e com várias turmas ja cadastradas, porém agora eu preciso da seguinte funcionalidade no sistema, eu precisei acrescentar uma coluna nova , que vai guardar o tempo de tolerância de entrada do aluno na portaria do clube, por exemplo se uma turma de natação  é criada, será cadastrado nela um tempo de tolerância em minutos, por exemplo 10 minutos, isso significa que o aluno só pode chegar até 10 minutos antes da aula, se ele chegar 20 minutos antes, o acesso é bloqueado. pois bem o problema é, como as turmas que já existem não fizeram ainda esta configuração, por padrão, vou deixar para estar turmas esta coluna com o valor de 15 (no caso 15 minutos), a pergunta é, como faço um script que ao invés de deixar a informação nas turmas que já existem como "null" deixe preenchido 15 por exemplo ?

estou usando sqlserver2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione a coluna com um valor padrão com a instrução `WITH VALUES` para que as linhas já existentes recebam esse valor, isso também vai lhe dar um respiro para ajustar o sistema que ainda terá de ser alterado para adicionar essa informação nas operações de CRUD.

```
   ALTER TABLE [TABELA] ADD [COLUNA] INT NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT Tabela_Coluna 
   DEFAULT (15)
   WITH VALUES
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro

Comment: @JoãoÁvila se a solução apresentada resolveu o seu problema você deve aceitá-la como resposta. Também seria interessante editar a sua pergunta adicionando a estrutra da sua tabela, nome e tipo da coluna que está adicionando. E para as próximas perguntas, se preocupe em sempre apresentar um [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

João, boa tarde!
Você tem que inserir a coluna como *nullable*, depois disso você faz um update nos registros já existentes para o valor de 15 minutos que você quer.

Uma vez feito isso e sabendo que o campo é obrigatório, você vai poder deixar o *non-nullable* e exigir preenchimento do sistema, do contrário terá uma exception.

Espero ter ajudado

*Update tabela set ColunaNova = 15*

****Você pode colocar o valor default como o amigo abaixo disse também, vai depender da necessidade da sua regra de negócio. Meu update não tem where pois entendo que você quer fazer esse processo uma única vez e que não tem registros novos já na tabela (onde eles já estejam preenchendo o valor dos minutos), se houver esses registros, favor considerar a cláusula *where colunanova is null*

Comment: Obrigado Angelo

Answer (score 1):

Há duas maneiras:

1) No Sql Management Studio 2017 clique na tabela com o botão direito e em Design.
   Selecione a coluna que você quer definir um valor Padrão.
   Em Propriedades da Coluna, na guia Geral, em Associação ou Valor Padrão defina como 15.
   Salve a tabela.

2) Execute um script:

```
UPDATE {table} SET {column} = 15 WHERE {column} IS NULL
```

Comment: Obrigado Weiner